Highlight the last table entry in color
I'm trying to display the last entry in the result table in color. Everything I've tried so far didn't work with ABAP 7.00. Here is the code for displaying the SALV table.

  DATA: lo_salv TYPE REF TO cl_salv_table,
        gr_display TYPE REF TO cl_salv_display_settings.

  SELECT * FROM zrechner INTO TABLE it_zrechres ORDER BY erstelldatum DESCENDING.

  DATA: lr_custom_container TYPE REF TO cl_gui_custom_container.

  CREATE OBJECT lr_custom_container
    EXPORTING
      container_name = 'CNT_SALV'.

  cl_salv_table=>factory(
    EXPORTING
      r_container = lr_custom_container
    IMPORTING
      r_salv_table = lo_salv
    CHANGING
      t_table      = it_zrechres ).

  gr_display = lo_salv->get_display_settings( ).
  gr_display->set_striped_pattern( value = 'X' ).

  lo_salv->display( ).
ENDFORM.                    "display_salv_table_result



Check following website: https://codezentrale.de/abap-salv-table-zeilen-farbig-anzeigen/

This link doesno`t help. It is the new syntax and I need the old one.

This should work.
report ztest_row_color_salv_alv.

data: lo_salv type ref to cl_salv_table,
      l_rows type i.

data: ls_color type lvc_s_scol,
      lt_color type lvc_t_scol.

types: begin of t_data,
  vbeln     like  vbak-vbeln,
  audat     like  vbak-audat,
  netwr     like  vbak-netwr,
  kunnr     like  vbak-kunnr,
  color     type  lvc_t_scol,
end of t_data.

data: lt_data type standard table of t_data,
      ls_data like line of lt_data.

field-symbols <f_data>  like line of lt_data.

*Filling the color structure
ls_color-color-col = 5."Green color
ls_color-color-int = 0.
ls_color-color-inv = 0.
append ls_color to lt_color.
clear ls_color.

*Selecting some sample data
select vbeln audat netwr kunnr up to 10 rows
into corresponding fields of table lt_data
from vbak.

 if sy-subrc = 0.
*---------------------------------------------------------------------------*
* New Syntax ABAP >= 7.4
*    l_rows = lines( lt_data )."Get number of rows
     "assign lt_data[ l_rows ] to <f_data> ."Get the last row
*---------------------------------------------------------------------------*
*---------------------------------------------------------------------------*
* Old Syntax ABAP
     describe table lt_data lines l_rows."
     read table lt_data assigning <f_data> index l_rows."Get the last row
*---------------------------------------------------------------------------*
     if sy-subrc = 0.
       <f_data>-color = lt_color[]."Set color to the last row
     endif.
 endif.

cl_salv_table=>factory(
  importing
      r_salv_table = lo_salv
  changing
      t_table = lt_data ).

lo_salv->get_columns( )->set_color_column( 'COLOR' ).
lo_salv->display( )."Show the Data


